# How can I write a single function that can be re-used by multiple fragments to navigate to a singular destination?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment-backstack

Let's say I have 4 fragments and navigate through them in the order
`A` -> `B` -> `C` -> `D` using a `NavController` object.

A is my home screen.

I'd like to write a single function called
`goToA()` that can be inherited and called from either `B`, `C` or `D` which navigates to  `A` and clears up the `back stack`

How do I go about that?

Comment: You could create a Global Action (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) that uses `popUpTo` to navigate to `A` and pop everything but that off the back stack (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop)

Answer (score 0):

In your `BaseFragment` just create the function:

```
protected fun goToA() {
    findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.<id of fragment A in the nav graph here>, false)
}
```

Now you can call this function from either `B`, `C` or `D`

Comment: FWIW, just an opinion.  https://levelup.gitconnected.com/android-nightmares-base-classes-ccf55dbd0604 https://proandroiddev.com/say-no-to-baseactivity-and-basefragment-83b156ed8998

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension function for it, defined at the top level outside any classes, that you can call from any of your Fragments:

```
fun Fragment.goToA() {
    //...
}
```